# Cherry MX Switch Tester with MX Silver (a.k.a. MX Speed)

Tags: keyboards

I am looking for a Cherry MX Switch Tester that contains an MX Silver (a.k.a. MX Speed). It should be below 50 USD. (otherwise I'll just purchase the entire keyboard)

---

All the Cherry MX Switch Testers I have found so far does not contain an MX Silver. Examples:

[WASD Cherry MX Switch Tester](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AZQKCD4) (16 USD) contains:

- 6 Different Cherry MX Switches: Cherry MX Green, Cherry MX Clear, Cherry MX Red, Cherry MX Black, Cherry MX Brown, and Cherry MX Blue
- 6 of each type of sound dampening O-rings: Red 40A-L and Blue 40A-R

[image]

[Max Keyboard Keycap, Cherry MX Switch, O-Ring Pro Sampler Tester Kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00N6DXTW4)  (22 USD) contains:

- [Cherry MX Red(1), MX Black(1), MX Blue(1), MX Brown(1), MX Green(1), MX Gray(1), MX Clear(1), MX White(1)]
- Sound dampening 50A (0.4mm reduction) rubber o-ring (Qty: 8)

[image]

[image]

[image]