# Topre Switch tester

Tags: keyboards

There exist several [Cherry MX Switch Testers](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2619/40). I am looking for a Topre Switch tester.

Ideally, it should contain the same key switches as the ones used in [Topre Realforce](https://deskthority.net/wiki/Topre_Realforce). The price should be cheaper than buying the full keyboard. I do not mind about shipping constraints.

---

So far, I have only found this [Switch Tester](https://www.massdrop.com/buy/cooler-master-switch-testerv2), which contains only one Topre Novatouch switch (and 5 Cherry MX: Black, Red, Brown, Blue, and Green switches). I would like more Topre switches.

[image]